# DependencyProperty Setter called After OnItemsSourceChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, itemssource

I need to access some Data when my ItemsSource changes so that I can correctly generate columns and bind in my DataGrid. To do this I need to bind different templates and choose them (Unfortunately CellTemplateSelector doesn't really work for me in this situation.)

It seems that in the following code the setter for TemplateListing is called AFTER OnItemsSourceChanged. Can anybody explain why or how to get around this?

```
public class SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing : DependencyObject
{
    public DataTemplate structTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate atomicTemplate { get; set; }
}

class SpreadsheetDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateListingProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TemplateListing", typeof(SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing), typeof(SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing TemplateListing
    {
        get { return (SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing)GetValue(TemplateListingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TemplateListingProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Collections.IEnumerable oldValue, System.Collections.IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        //Template listing is NULL
}}
```

Comment: did you try to change it before `base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);`

Comment: its null in this case too unfortunately

Comment: Why it should be not null? AFAIK, the order of dependency property assignment is undefined, especially when using data binding. You must handle changes of both properties.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to delay the initialization till the columns are loaded, then all properties are available.

```
public class SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing : DependencyObject
{
    public DataTemplate structTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate atomicTemplate { get; set; }
}

internal class SpreadsheetDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    private bool InitializeColumnsOnLoad = false;

    public SpreadsheetDataGrid()
    {
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        if (InitializeColumnsOnLoad)
        {
            InitializeColumns();
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateListingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TemplateListing", typeof (SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing),
            typeof (SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing TemplateListing
    {
        get { return (SpreadsheetCellTemplateListing) GetValue(TemplateListingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TemplateListingProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Collections.IEnumerable oldValue,
        System.Collections.IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        if (!IsLoaded)
        {
            InitializeColumnsOnLoad = true;
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeColumns();
        }
    }
}
```